# Polynomial with bounded coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $1<\beta<2$, I need to construct a polynomial (L can be chosen freely )$f(x)=x^{L}+a_{L-1}x^{L-1}+a_{L-2}x^{L-2}+\cdots+a_{1}x^{1}+a_0$
such that it satisfies

$$\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}|a_k|=1$$

and $f(\beta)=0$

Comment: $h_k=a_k$ maybe?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: I have edited carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Assume $f = X^L + \sum_{0 \le k < L} a_k X^k \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ is a polynomial such that $f(\beta) = 0$ with $\beta > 1$. Then we have

$$\beta^L = |\beta^L| = \left|-\sum_{0 \le k < L} a_k \beta^k\right| \le \sum_{0 \le k < L} |a_k| \beta^k \le \beta^{L-1} \sum_{0 \le k < L} |a_k| $$

So $1 < \beta \le \sum_{0 \le k < L} |a_k|$.

Comment: Thank you, but how can we construct a real polynomial which has the same form above, such that $f(\beta_i)=0$, $1\leq i\leq 2013$, where $\beta_i$  are all different and all in $(1\,,1+c)$ where c is a constant which you can choose by yourself, and the norm $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{L-1}|a_k|\leq 2$